# How to change volume of WAV file byte by byte in Java?

Tags: java, audio, wav

I can read WAV file (8-bit per sample) in the following function and copy it to another file. I want to play with the overall volume of the source file with given `scale` parameter, which is in range [0, 1]. My naive approach was to multiple byte with `scale` and convert it to byte again. All I got a noisy file. How can I achieve this byte by byte volume adjustment?

```
public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 10000;
public static final int WAV_HEADER_SIZE = 44;

public void changeVolume(File source, File destination, float scale) {
    RandomAccessFile fileIn = null;
    RandomAccessFile fileOut = null;

    byte[] header = new byte[WAV_HEADER_SIZE];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    try {
        fileIn = new RandomAccessFile(source, "r");
        fileOut = new RandomAccessFile(destination, "rw");

        // copy the header of source to destination file
        int numBytes = fileIn.read(header); 
        fileOut.write(header, 0, numBytes);

        // read & write audio samples in blocks of size BUFFER_SIZE
        int seekDistance = 0;
        int bytesToRead = BUFFER_SIZE;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;

        while(totalBytesRead < fileIn.length()) {
            if (seekDistance + BUFFER_SIZE <= fileIn.length()) {
                bytesToRead = BUFFER_SIZE;
            } else {
                // read remaining bytes                   
                bytesToRead = (int) (fileIn.length() - totalBytesRead);
            }

            fileIn.seek(seekDistance);
            int numBytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
            totalBytesRead += numBytesRead;

            for (int i = 0; i < numBytesRead - 1; i++) {
                // WHAT TO DO HERE?
                buffer[i] = (byte) (scale * ((int) buffer[i]));
            }

            fileOut.write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
            seekDistance += numBytesRead;
        }

        fileOut.setLength(fileIn.length());         
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File could not be found" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            fileIn.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A java byte is in a range from -128 to 127, while the byte used in the wav pcm format ranges from 0 to 255. That is most likely why you are changing your pcm data to random/noisy values.

buffer[i] = (byte) (scale * (buffer[i]<0?256+(int)buffer[i]:buffer[i]));